# In the rainshadow of an equatorial mountain, would savanna (Aw) or hot desert (Bwh) replace rainforest?

Tags: climate, earth-like, mountains, maps

[image]

This is a map of the area in question (pink/brown = mountains, lime = savanna, and dark green = rainforest). The top line is the equator, and lines are 10° apart. Would the area in the upper area of the central square be savanna or desert? (Off the image, there is land along the equator for a little under 1000 km east, and ocean almost immediately along the 10°S line.)

(This is on a fictional planet that is slightly colder than Earth, with a global average temperature of around 10-11 °C, if that helps.)

Comment: What do the various teal/cyan colors represent? And which direction is the prevailing wind?

Comment: There is no well-defined rainshadow in the [intertropical convergence zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertropical_Convergence_Zone) because there is no prevailing wind direction. For a practical example, look at the vegetation patterns around [Mount Kilimanjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilimanjaro_National_Park). (And anyway a mountain range *south* of the equator would have very little influence on the rain *north* of the equator. The two hemispheres don't share much in the way of wind.)

Comment: @Cadence Prevailing wind above the equator is east to west, below is west to east, but the equator is in the doldrums, where there is very little wind. | The various other colors are all water; that was an editing mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could probably, at least when considered superficially, be savanna, desert and rainforest mixed (almost) arbitrarily.

- [sometimes there are deserts right next to the ocean](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-and-where-are-coastal-deserts.html), due to cold oceanic streams and winds interacting in just the right way, especially on a cold planet such deserts may occurr.
- Furthermore as far as I know savanna often borders deserts, so you may find savanna there as well.
- Lastly, warm oceanic streams can transport heat and humidity, see for example how the gulf stream keeps europe warm and humid.
  If you had such a stream near the equator, it may sustain a rainforest.

So just set the oceanic streams and wind systems so that you obtain the climate you want near the ocean. You will probably fail conceiving physically realistic oceanic streams and wind systems, but if you dont make too obvious mistakes hardly anyone will be qualified to notice, I for shure wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be tropical rain forest (Af) or tropical monsoon (Am).

If you look at a comparable location in South America you will see the Amazon rain forest extends double your 1000 km to the eastern slopes of the Andes.

Comment: The Amazon is the side that gets the prevailing rain filled clouds. The Atacama desert is in the rain shadow of the Andes to the west of the Amazon.

Comment: There's no comparable mountain range in the above map to block westbound winds, and rain forests produce 70% of their own rain anyway.